# What is the difference between the ADMIN option and the GRANT option in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am studying SQL syntax for Oracle and have come across both an ADMIN option and a GRANT option for giving users the ability to grant privileges.  For example, if I want to give the SELECT privilege to user SCOTT on HR's EMPLOYEES table and give the ability to grant that access to someone else, I might do

```
GRANT SELECT ON HR.EMPLOYEES TO SCOTT WITH ADMIN OPTION
```

or

```
GRANT SELECT ON HR.EMPLOYEES TO SCOTT WITH GRANT OPTION.
```

It seems either is supposed to work.  Does anybody know what the difference is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [This](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_with_grant_admin_privileges.htm)

Both the “with grant” and “with admin” options serve to relinquish central security control, but they are for different types of privileges.

With Grant option:

- Only for object privileges, not system privileges.
- Only the person who granted the privilege can revoke the privilege.
- Revoked privileges can "cascade", allowing the first grantor to revoke many
  subsequent grants.

With Admin option:

- Only for system privileges, not object privileges.

Comment: That helps.  So if userA grants a privilege to userB with GRANT and userB grants to userC with GRANT, and userA revokes the privilge from userB, that also causes userC to lose the privilege?  Would userC keep the privilege if  ADMIN had been used?

Comment: + 1 @ Paul J Abernathy Yes, It will since the grant is chained and goes back to the Original granter( userA). revoking userB will impact userB privileges as well.

Comment: Can userA revoke the privilege from userC, who was granted for by userB ?